# How to handle UITapGestureRecognizer on views created in loops?

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a vertical UIStackView and i append a horizontal UIStackView and some UILabels inside this view. I attach the UITapGestureRecognizer to handle the tap actions. How can i change for example the label(which is a subview) when i tap on a row?

Here is my code so far:

```
for article in articleType {
    //Create a row
    let row = UIStackView()
    row.axis = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal
    
    //Create a label and indicator
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = article.label

    let indicator = UILabel()
    indicator.text = "off"

    //Add label to row and row to parent stack view
    row.addSubView(label)
    row.addSubView(indicator)
    mainUiStackView.addArrangedSubview(row)

    //Create tap handled
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(sender:)))
    row.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    print(sender.view)

    //This is where i'm stuck, how can i change the second label's text to "on" for example?
    sender.view.indicator.text = "on"

}
```

Comment: You cannot tap on a stack view.

Comment: @matt, why not? I just created a test app where I added tap gesture recognizers to both the arranged subviews and to the stack view and they both fired as expected. (I had to tap in the spaces between the subviews in order for the stack view's tap gesture recognizer to fire, but it worked.)

Comment: @DuncanC Well, maybe they changed this. It used to be that a stack view was a special kind of view.

Comment: So each stack view will always contain exactly 2 labels, and when the user taps on a given stack view, you always want to reach into the stack view and set it's label text to "on"?

Comment: Yes. I actually want to change a checkbox image to on/off, but used a UILabel in the example code so its not that complicated, but the logic would apply the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code goes through a loop and creates a whole series of stack views in the local variable `row`. Then you don't add those stack views to your view hierarchy, so they get "dropped on the floor."

For this line:

```
let row = UIStackView()
```

After each pass through your for loop, that stack view you create will go out of scope and be deallocated.

### Edit:

After you pointed it out, I see now where you add your `row` stack views to your `mainUiStackView`.

I gather based on the comments you've made that you want to have taps on one of your "row" stack views set the `indicator` label in that stack view to "on".

I would suggest building an array of your row stack views and their label views (As structs). Then find the row that was tapped and set it's label to the on state:

```
struct RowStackViewStruct { 
   let stackView: UIStackView
   let label: UILabel
}

var rowStackViews = [RowStackViewStruct]()


for article in articleType {
    //Create a row
    let row = UIStackView()
    row.axis = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal
    
    //Create a label and indicator
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = article.label

    let indicator = UILabel()
    indicator.text = "off"

    //Add label to row and row to parent stack view
    row.addSubView(label)
    row.addSubView(indicator)
    mainUiStackView.addArrangedSubview(row)

    //Create tap handled
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(sender:)))
    row.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    //Build a RowStackViewStruct for this row
    let newRowStackViewStruct = RowStackViewStruct(stackView: row,
      label: indicator)
    rowStackViews.append(newRowStackViewStruct)
}

And then in your tap handler code:

@objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    print(sender.view)

    if let aStruct = rowStackViews.first(where: { sender?.view == $0.stackView }) {
       aStruct.label.text = "on"
}
```

I banged the above code out in the SO editor. It likely contains minor syntax errors, and is intended as a guide, not copy-paste code that you can drop in.

It seems like you should really keep track of the on-off state of your rows. It seems like you should have an array of model objects that represent the state of your rows, and use that to build and maintain your main vertical stack view. In fact, it might be better to switch to a table view or collection view, since those are made to be driven from a model.

Comment: Hi! This part of the code actually works fine. The issue i'm having is to how to access a specific UILabel subview after a tap on the whole row. So sender.view.indicator.text obviously not going to work, but i don't know how to access this on/off label without having an IBOutlet for it(and i don't have that, since i'm creating these labels in a loop from code)

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete, as is your description of what you want to do. The code you posted would not work for the reasons I pointed out in my answer. If you are trying to have a tap on a stack view figure out which view inside the stack view was tapped, edit your question to say that, and say it clearly. It is maddening to have to play 20 questions to figure out what somebody is asking.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure what you mean. I add the whole row to another UIStackView in this line: mainUiStackView.addArrangedSubview(row). The tap action works fine on the row, the print(sender.view) correctly logs the action for each row separately. I don't want to add a tap gesture to the UILabels inside the row, just the main row. And when the main row is tapped, i want to change one of the label's text inside this row. This is what i described in my question, i don't know how to make it more clearer.

Comment: I missed that line. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, only one thing to change, updated your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the `isUserInteractionEnabled` property of whichever label you want to tap on is set to `true` because it's set to `false` by default.

```swift
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let tappedView = sender.view else { return }
    let location = sender.location(in: tappedView.superview)
    if case let hitView as UILabel = tappedView.hitTest(location, with: nil) {
        hitView.text = hitView.text == "off" ? "on" : "off"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i think i wasn't clear in my question. So i want the tap action to run in the whole row. When i tap on the row(anywhare, not on a specific sub-view), i want to change a subview's UILabel value from off to on. So this would be easy if i have an IBOutlet for the second UILabel, but since i generate them from code and in a loop, not sure how to access these labels in the handleTap function.